# Weird behaviour regarding visibility of symbols in C++

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, visibility, dynamic-linking

I was trying to hide all symbols in a shared object file except for a certain selection
The hiding part I was doing via `-fvisibility=hidden` compiler option
The exception part I was doing via `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` compiler extension, marking the relevant functions with it
Issues arose when I tried doing this on templated functions, they sometimes wouldn't be global/external/dynamic (and sometimes would)

Compiler versions:

```
$ for compiler in g++ g++-10 ~/GCC-12/bin/g++ clang; do echo "compiler: $compiler"; $compiler --version; done
compiler: g++
g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

compiler: g++-10
g++-10 (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.3.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

compiler: /home/ilazaric/GCC-12/bin/g++
g++ (GCC) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

compiler: clang
clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Running everything in the Ubuntu On Windows VM (wsl)

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

EXAMPLE OF ISSUE

code.cpp:

```
struct Defined {};
struct Declared;

template<typename T>
int __attribute__((visibility("default"))) should_be_dynamic_symbol(){return 42;}

const int force_instantiation =
  should_be_dynamic_symbol<int>() +
  should_be_dynamic_symbol<Defined>() +
  should_be_dynamic_symbol<Declared>() +
  0;
```

script.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
for compiler in g++ g++-10 ~/GCC-12/bin/g++ clang
do
    echo "compiler: $compiler"
    $compiler -o code.so code.cpp -shared -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden
    nm -C code.so | grep should_be_dynamic_symbol
    rm code.so
done
```

In terminal:

```
$ ./script.sh
compiler: g++
0000000000001186 t int should_be_dynamic_symbol<Defined>()
0000000000001195 t int should_be_dynamic_symbol<Declared>()
0000000000001177 W int should_be_dynamic_symbol<int>()
compiler: g++-10
0000000000001185 t int should_be_dynamic_symbol<Defined>()
0000000000001194 t int should_be_dynamic_symbol<Declared>()
0000000000001176 W int should_be_dynamic_symbol<int>()
compiler: /home/ilazaric/GCC-12/bin/g++
0000000000001169 t int should_be_dynamic_symbol<Defined>()
0000000000001174 t int should_be_dynamic_symbol<Declared>()
000000000000115e W int should_be_dynamic_symbol<int>()
compiler: clang
0000000000001170 t int should_be_dynamic_symbol<Defined>()
0000000000001180 t int should_be_dynamic_symbol<Declared>()
0000000000001160 W int should_be_dynamic_symbol<int>()
```

Note from the terminal output above, first two symbols are marked `t`, which means they are local/normal, while the third symbol is marked `W`, which makes it global/external/dynamic (coming from `man nm` documentation)
My issue:
Why are the symbols for `Defined` and `Declared` function template local, while the `int` one is global/external?
What I was expecting: all three symbols to be global
Considering that `clang` and `g++` are doing the same thing I'm assuming that it's not a compiler bug but an error in my understanding

Comment: gcc has a bunch of issues about visibility, I really doubt it's a bug. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102380

Comment: The issue with the `gcc` visibility flag and attributes persists, though I have managed to do this in another way, not using the `gcc` stuff anymore, using `objcopy` options `--localize-symbols` and `--globalize-symbols`